# memory limit by calculation

Tags: memory, memory-limit, memory-size

lets suppose a

> 32 bit computer...

in that each cell has 4 bytes...now a memory cell can only be accessed distinctly as it is a 32 bit computer only

> x=(2^32)-1 memory cells

can be addressed...so total no. of bytes is

> y=x*4.

so the gigabytes come out to be

> y/(1024^3)=16...

if only 16gb can be accessed how come we have 80 gb and even more memory computers which can access all data stored in the memory

Answer (score 2):

Your numbers are off - the minimum addressable unit is a byte, so the number of available bytes is:

```
x=(2^32)
```

or 4Gb. We can have larger sizes than this because we now have 64-bit architectures.

Comment: There is no need for the `-1`

Comment: i am very confused... if we can access only 4 gb...what about the computer hard disk memory which is much more than 4 gb and can be accessed

Comment: @Snu You need to read a book on computer architectures - hard disk != memory. and this is not the right place to discuss such things.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it's not typical for an OS to permit access to memory > 4GB for a 32-bit computer - at least, they don't make such access easy.

Check out [AWE (Address Windowing Extensions)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Windowing_Extensions) - Windows means of getting to > 4GB on a 32-bit box.  SQL Server can be configured to use AWE to increase the memory available for certain operations.

Access to memory > 4GB is likely to come at a "high price" in terms of performance.  If you want > 4GB RAM then your best bet is a 64-bit processor.

Comment: A i am very confused... if we can access only 4 gb...what about the computer hard disk memory which is much more than 4 gb and can be accessed